# Display image on key press and have it remain on the screen until thread is stopped

Tags: java, image, background, while-loop, key

I am wanting to make a naughts and crosses game so you use your mouse to select a box and then X or O on the keyboard to input an answer. I have got as far as getting the box selection working but can't seem to get the x and o working. My code probably isn't the best as this is my first game I am making.

Here is my main class:

```
package com;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener,
        KeyListener {

    public int box = 1;
    public int x, y;
    public int cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2, cx3, cy3, cx4, cy4, cx5, cy5;

    public boolean player1 = true;
    public boolean player2 = false;
    public boolean box1 = false;
    public boolean box2 = false;
    public boolean box3 = false;
    public boolean box4 = false;
    public boolean box5 = false;
    public boolean box6 = false;
    public boolean box7 = false;
    public boolean box8 = false;
    public boolean box9 = false;
    public boolean xpress = false;
    public boolean cross1 = false;
    public boolean cross2 = false;
    public boolean cross3 = false;
    public boolean cross4 = false;
    public boolean cross5 = false;

    public Thread t;
    Timer time;

    JButton cross, naught;

    Image Board, Select, Cross, Cross2, Cross3, Cross4, Cross5, Naught;

    Board() {
        super();
        x = 0;
        y = 60;

        t = new Thread();
        time = new Timer(5, this);
        time.start();
        t.start();
        setFocusable(true);

        addMouseListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/images/Board_N+C.png"));
        Board = i.getImage();
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/images/Select_N+C.png"));
        Select = i1.getImage();
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/images/Cross_N+C.png"));
        Cross = i2.getImage();
        Cross2 = i2.getImage();
        Cross3 = i2.getImage();
        Cross4 = i2.getImage();
        Cross5 = i2.getImage();

        ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "/images/Naught_N+C.png"));
        Naught = i3.getImage();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(Board, 0, 60, null);
        if (cross1) {

        }

        if (x < 170 && y < 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 0, 60, null);

            repaint();
        } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 170, 60, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 340, 60, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 170 && y < 400 && y > 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 0, 230, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 400 && y > 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 170, 230, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 400 && y > 230 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 340, 230, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 170 && y < 570 && y > 400 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 0, 400, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 570 && y > 400 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 170, 400, null);
            repaint();

        } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 570 && y > 400 && !xpress) {
            g2d.drawImage(Select, 340, 400, null);
            repaint();
        }
        if (xpress && !player2) {
            if (x < 170 && y < 230) {
                cross1 = true;
                while (cross1) {
                    g2d.drawImage(Cross, 0, 60, null);
                    System.out.println("Cross");

                }repaint();
                xpress = false;
            } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 230) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 230) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 170 && y < 400 && y > 230) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 400 && y > 230) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 400 && y > 230) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 170 && y < 570 && y > 400) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 340 && x > 170 && y < 570 && y > 400) {
                repaint();

            } else if (x < 510 && x > 340 && y < 570 && y > 400) {
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == e.VK_X) {
            if (player1) {
                xpress = true;
                player1 = false;
                player2 = true;
            }
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

How do you display an image at a key press and have it remain on the screen until the thread is stopped?

Hope someone can help. If you need more information just ask.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I think it's in the title.

Comment: General tips:  1) `g2d.drawImage(Select, 0, 60, null);` should be `g2d.drawImage(Select, 0, 60, this);` 2) Probably easier done using the images as icons for buttons in a grid layout. 3) For Swing, look into key bindings over using a `KeyListener`. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Nate  Oh right, I always 'read & forget' the title.

Comment: DON'T call `repaint` from WITHIN ANY paint method.  This will resulting in a program that consumes your CPU. If you're in a paint method, you're already undergoing a repaint, don't alter the component in anyway that might trigger a repaint - this is incredibly bad

Comment: Please learn java naming conventios and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have no idea of how threads work in Java.

```
t = new Thread();
time = new Timer(5, this);
time.start();
t.start();
```

Firstly, the creation of the `Thread` will do nothing (other then have a thread start and promptly die cause it's not doing anything).

Secondly, you better have a SERIOUSLY good reason for firing a timer every 5 milliseconds.  This is going to throttle the Event Dispatching Thread, eventually consuming your CPU and bringing your program to a grinding halt.

Take the time to have a read through

- [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

**EXAMPLE**

Here's a really quick example, BYO image...

```
public class PopShowAndFadeImage {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame test = new JFrame("Test");
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setSize(700, 1000);
        test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        test.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        test.add(new ImagePane());
        test.setVisible(true);

    }

    protected static class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        private Image image;
        private Timer timeOut;

        public ImagePane() {

            timeOut = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    image = null;
                    repaint();

                }
            });
            timeOut.setRepeats(false);
            timeOut.setCoalesce(true);

            setFocusable(true);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "HitMe");
            am.put("HitMe", new AbstractAction() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (background == null) {
                        try {
                            background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/MT011.gif"));
                        } catch (IOException exp) {
                            exp.printStackTrace();;
                        }
                    }

                    image = background;

                    repaint();

                    timeOut.restart();

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (image != null) {

                int width = getWidth() - 1;
                int height = getHeight() - 1;

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                int x = (width - image.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (height - image.getHeight(this)) / 2;

                g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, this);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Just a quick overview of some of the issues you are facing.

You admit to been new to Java/programming, but you're already leaping into custom graphics and animation.  Custom graphics is difficult enough, animation is an order of magnitude more so.

Here is some of the background elements your going to need.

- Good understanding basic programming principles (if, loops, etc) - this is basic stuff
- Good understanding of Object Oriented Programming.  This is none trivial for most people
- Good understanding of Swing API, especially how painting works
- Good understanding of the Graphics/Graphics2D API. This can be none trivial
- Good understanding of Threads and how they related to the Swing API. This is none trivial
- At least a basic understanding of animation principles.

From what you're saying, it appears as if your trying to fly before you've mastered crawling.  I'm not saying you can't do it, but there are significant gaps in your understanding and knowledge which are going to make it difficult to reach your goals.

When it comes to animation, I use the [Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home), but you could also look at [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)

I'm going to try and put some examples together, but the one I posted earlier will do exactly as your title has requested

Comment: The take the time to go through the [Java Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), they're an excellent resource

Comment: Yes I'm new at java and don't know what half the things are. I was using the timer to have an animated selector frame move to each square but forgot to remove it.  Could you show an example that relates to my project as i desperately need help.     Thanx

Comment: Ive gone through a lot of the Java Trails but i can't seem to come up with an idea on how to get this project to work without using buttons. I really like it so far but it just won't work.

Comment: The example code I posted earlier will exactly as your title requests

Comment: With the example you posted - the timer has an error saying "Remove arguments to match Timer()" What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use javax.swing.Timer, not java.uti.timer

Comment: where it says time = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){})

Comment: And you're using a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)? Cause that's the only constructor it has

Comment: Yep - i don't know whats going on this time - think it might be time to move on to another -Easier project.

Comment: I'd start a new project and try creating a simple timer that just outputs some text or something, so you can become familiar with it

Comment: Yeah - Do you have any suggestions on a good beginner game project with simple graphics like drawing images?

Comment: Sure, try a simple image browser. Read images from a folder and display them.  Should give an opportunity to play with key bindings and image scaling and custom painting

Comment: nice i will try it - Thanx for your help. I learned quite a lot out of this. shame my naughts and crosses game can't be continued but maybe in the future i can come back to it.